# Reading a .doc extension file ,ElementTree

Tags: xml, python-2.7, docx, elementtree, doc

I have successfully read `.docx` files using ElementTree package using `zipfile`. But I realized that there isn't the archive '`word/document.xml`'for `.doc` files . I looked into the docs but did not find any. How can it be read? 
For docx, i used :

```
import zipfile as zf
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
z = zf.ZipFile("test.docx")
doc_xml = z.open('word/document.xml')
tree = ET.parse(doc_xml)
```

Using the above for .doc gives :

```
KeyError: "There is no item named 'word/document.xml' in the archive"
```

I saw something for read in ElementTree docs but that is for xml files only.

```
doc_xml = open('yesblue.doc','r')
```

How should go about this one? Maybe something like converting `.doc` into `.docx` in python itself.

Edit: The .doc format stores data in binary and XML cannot be used for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some serious searching ,I realized that it would be better to use the comtypes package to convert it from `.doc` to `.docx` format. This has its own set of disadvantages like `Windows exclusivity` and the need for Microsoft Office installed.

```
import sys
import os
import comtypes.client
in_file = os.path.abspath('')
out_file = os.path.abspath('yesblue') #name of output file added to the current working directory 
word = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')
doc = word.Documents.Open('yesblue.doc') #name of input file
doc.SaveAs(out_file, FileFormat=16)  # output file format to Office word Xml default (code=16)
doc.Close()
word.Quit()
```

The list of codes are contained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff839952.aspx).

The output `docx` file can be used for further processing in ElementTree.